# MAMP: PHP not working inside subdirectories within htdocs folder

Tags: php, macos, mamp, subdirectory

```
phpinfo();
```

The above function works inside htdocs folder but not within subdirectories, it just displays the text as if it where an HTML file

Comment: Sounds like it could be a permissions thing. Check to see the folder doesn't have restricted permissions

Comment: Permissions are set to Read & Write...

Comment: Are you using .html files or .php files? You may have .htaccess files in the subdirectories, or maybe it's only in the root folder. Send more info on your file extension and .htaccess files.

Comment: should I add an .htaccess file to the subdirectories with the php version added as a rule?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure file that isn't working has .php extension and has `<?php` tag?

Comment: course, same files work in parent folder but not within subdirectories

Comment: do you have the open <?php tag?